# Editing the Reddit Enhancement Suite's Userbar

Tags: css, html, reddit

I'm currently trying to edit the RES userbar for my subreddit. It looks like this:

[image: this]

It also collapses.

I want to float almost all of the elements to the right so that they are lined up vertically. The html for the bar is:

```
<div id="header-bottom-right" class="res-navTop">
  <div id="userbarToggle" title="Toggle Userbar" class="userbarHide">»</div>
  <span class="user">
    <a href="http://www.reddit.com/user/snowe2010/" style="margin-right: 2px;">
      snowe2010
    </a>
    <span id="RESAccountSwitcherIcon"></span>
    &nbsp;(
    <span class="userkarma" title="">
      <a title="link karma" href="/user/snowe2010/submitted/">9</a> 
      · 
      <a title="comment karma" href="/user/snowe2010/comments/">
      2170
      </a>
    </span>
    )
    </span>
    <span class="separator">|</span>
    <a title="no new mail" href="http://www.reddit.com/message/inbox/" class="nohavemail" id="mail"></a>
    <a id="mailCount" href="/message/unread/"></a>
    <span class="separator">|</span>
    <a title="no new mod mail" href="http://www.reddit.com/message/moderator/" class="nohavemail" id="modmail">mod messages</a>
    <span class="separator">|</span>
    <ul class="flat-list hover">
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.reddit.com/prefs/" class="pref-lang">preferences</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="separator">|</span>
  <span id="openRESPrefs">
    <span id="RESSettingsButton" title="RES Settings" class="gearIcon newNotification">
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="separator">|</span>
  <form method="post" action="/logout" class="logout hover">
    <input type="hidden" name="uh" value="zoimwqbhhl59526448277e691374c3d0bc47706bb35d0045b9">
    <input type="hidden" name="top" value="off">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$(this).parent().submit()">logout</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

I've currently tried setting each element to a block and then floating right, but that isn't working. I've also tried setting them to display: table-cell; and aligning it, but that isn't working either.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/csshelp/submit or 
http://www.reddit.com/r/enhancement/submit  -- pick the right place for your questions

Comment: @andytuba: You make it sound like questions involving Reddit have no place on SO.

Comment: @andytuba Ok I'll change the question.. I have a div that looks exactly like the above. It has absolutely nothing to do with reddit. I need to make it so that all the elements are stacked on top of each other and floated to the right. Can you help me with this? I've tried a few things similar to the ones listed above.

Comment: yeah, okay, sorry.. i'm not good with design things like this, but lemme whip up a quick-and-dirty thing that might help.

Comment: it's ok. It's just more that it's css than reddit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header-bottom-right a {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

#header-bottom-right .separator { display: none; }
```

This is a pretty unrefined approach, but it's a starter.  There's plenty of room for smoothing out the rough edges if you want to continue with this approach.

[image]

Comment: I had specified that I already tried this in my post above. I'm looking for help with the refining bit :\. It also looks different every time I load the page for some reason.